# Simple chat Application using SIP and RTP

Tags: java, sip, voip, rtsp, rtp

I would like to create a simple JAVA voice chat application using SIP and RTP. Actually I understand the theoretical concepts of SIP,RTP, RTCP and also RTSP.But, when it comes to JAVA programming I don't know how to start! Any Ideas?

Comment: Why Java? Is that going to run inside a browser? Is that an Android App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've done it since a while and I thought of sharing it with other beginners like me. I've used the Android SIP API which is very simple to understand, and used the Mobicents TOMCAT SIP Servlet as my SIP server. It works like charm!